# Setting Z-index of autocomplete dropdown, and using getOptionSelected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing the Autocomplete material ui widget in my webApp, but the drop down is rendering behind my edit panel. I can use my arrow keys to select options, but I can't see the pop up. If I remove either of the following css property {position: "fixed"} or {"z-index": "2000"} it works, but my edit panel will no longer look correct. So it seems that I need to be able to set the zindex of the drop down to 2001 or some thing, but i am unsure as to how or if this is the best solution.

Also I am trying to set the initial value of the dropdown box to "ACCU-SEAL 35-532 Bag Sealer" but get the following error:

`Material-UI: the 'getOptionLabel' method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for "ACCU-SEAL 35-532 Bag Sealer".`

so I tried to add the following to my Autocomplete:

`getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.label === value}`

but I get the same error.

I have an example of my code up here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fv075?file=/formElementsEdit.jsx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `disablePortal` prop to make sure that the menu will be rendered under the current node:

```
<Autocomplete
    ....
    disablePortal
    ....
/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I have been trying to figure this out for a week. Do you have any suggestions on how to get an initial value in the Autocomplete box?

Comment: You can use the `defaultValue` prop for non-controlled element, or the `value` for a controlled one.

Comment: When i use value i get the following error:

``Material-UI: the value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with "ACCU-SEAL 35-532 Bag Sealer".
You can use the getOptionSelected prop to customize the equality test.``

so thats why i am trying to use getOptionSelected, but for some reason its still not working. Any help?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fv075?file=/formElementsEdit.jsx

If you look in the console there are 3 errors, and the autocomplete box doesnt have a default value.

Comment: Question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418401/setting-default-value-of-material-ui-autocomplete/61418599#61418599

Comment: You just saved my life , thank you so much