# Setting default value of Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set the initial value of the Autocomplete to "ACCU-SEAL 35-532 Bag Sealer" but get the following error:

Material-UI: the 'getOptionLabel' method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for "ACCU-SEAL 35-532 Bag Sealer".

so I tried to add the following to my Autocomplete:

```
getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.label === value}
```

but I get the same error.

I have an example of my code up here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fv075?file=/formElementsEdit.jsx

Any help in setting the initial value of the autocomplete would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use have `options` in the Autocomplete, you should use the same values that your options contains.

In your examples each option is an object with `value` and `label`. Since you use that `label` in the `getOptionLabel` function - you should use at least the `label` in the object that you are passing.

Option #1:

```
const value = "ACCU-SEAL 35-532 Bag Sealer";
...
<Autocomplete
    ...
    value={{label: value}}
```

Option #2:

```
const value = "ACCU-SEAL 35-532 Bag Sealer";
...
<Autocomplete
    ...
    value={{label: value, value: 1}}
```

Option #3:
    ...

In any of the above options - the value of the property `value` should be an object with at least one key - the `label` key.

Check the following example based on your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zzfh7?file=/formElementsEdit.jsx

Comment: Option 1 worked perfectly, Thank you for all the support your freaking awesome